# How to handle only those exceptions in controller which are thrown outside rest method in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I've got a question about error handling in Spring.

There is @ExceptionHandler annotation for handling exceptions in controller. For example I need to handle invalid json and this will work:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public  ResponseEntity<Object> handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
   //Method logic
}
```

But! In this case if we throw HttpMessageNotReadableException inside rest method, then @ExceptionHandler will catch it anyway. So the question is: How can I handle only these exceptions which are thrown before we actually get into rest method?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle exception which are thrown before we actually get into rest method"? `ExceptionHandler` comes only into picture when the thread enters the Rest controller.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala, I mean (for example) that if we expect some POJO in '@RequestBody' in rest method and client sends us invalid json which is had to be deserialized into our POJO, then 'HttpMessageNotReadableException' will be thrown before entering our rest method and '@ExceptionHandler' can handle this exception.

Comment: Why would you want to handle such exceptions? Application/Tomcat container takes of such errors and displays errors to client.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala, "Application/Tomcat container takes of such errors and displays errors to client."
I want to customize response for client.

Comment: In my opinion, you do not get access to such exceptions because the thread is still outside the control of Spring MVC.